# how to fill custom color in pie am 5 chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts5

I am working on a project for that I am using am 5 chart for creating pie chart. I have customized It's value but unable to change it's colors. Right now It is showing default colors. I have to change it's colors - red, green, blue, yellow, orange. Kindly help me . how can I change these colors.

this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
  <body>
    <div id="chartdiv"></div>
    <script src="index_am.js"></script>
    <script src="percent.js"></script>
    <script src="Animated.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>



      <script>
          am5.ready(function () {

              // Create root element
              // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
              var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

              // Set themes
              // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
              root.setThemes([
                am5themes_Animated.new(root)
              ]);

              // Create chart
              // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/
              var chart = root.container.children.push(
                am5percent.PieChart.new(root, {
                    startAngle: 160, endAngle: 380
                })
              );

              // Create series
              // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/#Series

              //var series0 = chart.series.push(
              //  am5percent.PieSeries.new(root, {
              //      valueField: "Percents",
              //      categoryField: "Rating",
              //      startAngle: 160,
              //      endAngle: 380,
              //      radius: am5.percent(70),
              //      innerRadius: am5.percent(65)
              //  })
              //);

              //var colorSet = am5.ColorSet.new(root, {
              //    colors: [series0.get("colors").getIndex(0)],
              //    passOptions: {
              //        lightness: -0.05,
              //        hue: 0
              //    }
              //});

              //series0.set("colors", colorSet);

              //series0.ticks.template.set("forceHidden", true);
              //series0.labels.template.set("forceHidden", true);

              var series1 = chart.series.push(
                am5percent.PieSeries.new(root, {
                    startAngle: 160,
                    endAngle: 380,
                    valueField: "bottles",
                    innerRadius: am5.percent(80),
                    categoryField: "Rating"
                })
              );

              series1.ticks.template.set("forceHidden", true);
              series1.labels.template.set("forceHidden", true);

              var label = chart.seriesContainer.children.push(
                am5.Label.new(root, {
                    textAlign: "center",
                    centerY: am5.p100,
                    centerX: am5.p50,
                    text: "[fontSize:18px]total[/]:\n[bold fontSize:30px]1647.9[/]"
                })
              );

              var data = [
                {
                    Rating: "A",
                    bottles: 1500,

                },
                {
                    Rating: "B",
                    bottles: 990
                },
                {
                    Rating: "C",
                    bottles: 785
                },
                {
                    Rating: "D",
                    bottles: 255
                },
                {
                    Rating: "E",
                    bottles: 452
                },

              ];

              // Set data
              // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/#Setting_data
              //series0.data.setAll(data);
              series1.data.setAll(data);

          }); // end am5.ready()
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First define a custom color set, with the desired colors.

```js
var colorSet = new am5.ColorSet(root, {
  colors: [
    am5.color("red"),
    am5.color("green"),
    am5.color("blue"),
    am5.color("yellow"),
    am5.color("orange")
  ]
});
```

Then set the color set for the chart series.

```js
series1.set("colors", colorSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem in **Vue 3** with the **amCharts 5**.

My solution was doing this:

```js
// membersPerCountryData structure
membersPerCountryData: [
{
 countryName: 'Portugal',
 countryIso: 'pt',
 percentageOfTotal: 0.5,
 numberOfMembers: 100,
 countryColor: #ff0000, //red
},
{
 countryName: 'Brazil',
 countryIso: 'br',
 percentageOfTotal: 0.5,
 numberOfMembers: 100,
 countryColor: #00ff00, //green
}
]
```

MembersPerCountryDonutChart.vue

```js
...
    props: {
      membersPerCountryData: {
        required: true,
        default: () => [],
        type: Array,
      },
    },
    data() {
      return {
        root: null,
      };
    },

    mounted() {
      let root = am5.Root.new(this.$refs.chartdiv);

      //Create an array with all the colors you desire to see for each searies of the pieChart

      let assignedColors = (numberOfColors) => {
        let colors = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < numberOfColors; i++) {
          colors.push(am5.color(this.membersPerCountryData[i].countryColor));
        }
        return colors;
      };

      let chartColors = assignedColors(this.membersPerCountryData.length);

     // Create your own color pallete
      var colorSet = am5.ColorSet.new(root, {
        colors: chartColors,
      });

      root.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(root)]);

      let chart = root.container.children.push(
        am5percent.PieChart.new(root, {
          layout: root.verticalLayout,
          innerRadius: am5.percent(50),
        }),
      );

      // Create series
      // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/#Series
      var series = chart.series.push(
        am5percent.PieSeries.new(root, {
          valueField: 'numberOfMembers',
          categoryField: 'countryName',
        }),
      );

      //Set your color pallete
      series.set('colors', colorSet);

      // Set data
      // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/#Setting_data
      series.data.setAll(this.membersPerCountryData);

      // Remove labels
      series.labels.template.setAll({
        text: '',
      });

      // Play initial series animation
      // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/#Animation_of_series
      series.appear(1000, 100);

      // Remove Logo
      root._logo.dispose();

      this.root = root;
    },

    beforeDestroy() {
      if (this.root) {
        this.root.dispose();
      }
    },
...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).